# how to handle the selenium script to validate the completion of report which takes 20 minutes using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In my project, the end to workflow is generating a particular report and validate the report details with data base after the completion of the report. The report will be in progress status right after click on generate button. It will take 15 to 25 minutes to get completed and show the status in UI. I want to know how to handle this and wait for report until it gets completed and proceed with report vs DB validation?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work I guess:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 1800);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("successStatus")));
```

Replace `getDriver()` with your WebDriver, `1800` with the amount of seconds you want to wait and `successStatus` with the element id that shows your success message (or any other By object that suits your needs).